# Given a continuous charge distribution of a sphere calculate the electric field away:

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, physics

What is the electric field inside the sphere a radius r (the sphere has a radius a), and outside the sphere $R>a$?
Given a sphere of volume:
$$V=\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$

The sphere has a radius of $r=a$, calculate the electric field some radius $r$ within the sphere.
Since it has uniform charge density I assume this:
$$dQ=\rho \ dV$$

Then I use the following integral to make do of my calculations:
$$E= k \int_\limits{r}^{a} \frac{dQ}{r^2}$$
I make this necessary substitution which leads me into the following:
$$E=k\int_\limits{r}^{a}\frac{\rho}{r^2}dV$$
Afterwards I make usage of this $dV= 4 \pi r^2 \ dr$

Leading me to reduce my expression farther into this expression:
$$E=k\int_\limits{r}^{a}\frac{4 \rho \pi r^2 }{r^2}dr $$

Which reduces to the following:
$$E=k\int_\limits{r}^{a}4 \rho \pi \ dr$$

I assume this to be the answer:

$$E= 4k\rho \pi(a-r)$$

Using this method I calculated a radius R outside the sphere using the similar method which got me:
$$E = 4 k \rho (R-a)$$

Comment: Are you measuring the electric field $r$ away from the center of the sphere (radially)?

Comment: @AlexVong Yes or a point an r away

Comment: Are the charge uniformly distributed inside the sphere or only on the boundary?

Comment: @AlexVong Inside the sphere as a whole

Comment: Are you familiar with the divergence theorem?

Comment: @user No why? I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Look up in google. With the help of the theorem one obtains the result immediately.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky You may also want to read this: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node30.html

Comment: @AlexVong So I don't need bounds then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a single point charge situated at the point ${\bf r_0}$. Its field:
$$
{\bf E}({\bf r})=k\frac{{\bf r}-{\bf r_0}}{|{\bf r}-{\bf r_0}|^3}
$$
is prominent by its unique property being divergenceless everywhere except for the origin:
$$
\nabla\cdot {\bf E}({\bf r})=4\pi k\delta({\bf r}-{\bf r_0}).
$$

Therefore by the [divergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) the flux of the field through a closed surface is  proportional to the charge contained inside the surface.

From the symmetry of your problem the field at a point is directed along the line connecting the point with the center of the sphere and depends only on the distance from the center $r$:

$$\begin{cases}
r<a:& 4\pi r^2 E(r)=4\pi k\dfrac{4\pi}3 r^3 \rho \implies E(r)=k\dfrac{4\pi\rho}{3}r,\\
r>a:& 4\pi r^2 E(r)=4\pi k\dfrac{4\pi}3 a^3 \rho \implies E(r)=k\dfrac{4\pi\rho }{3}\dfrac{a^3}{r^2}.
\end{cases}
$$