# Is there a calculus attempt at this question:

Tags: integration, physics, indefinite-integrals

This question is based on the electric field.
This is the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166528/given-a-continuous-charge-distribution-of-a-sphere-calculate-the-electric-field) which I would like to solve using this integral:
This is the equation for Electric Field.
$$E=\int \frac{dq}{r^s}$$
I was wondering if this approach was valid?

This is volume charge density and an exression can developed that states:

> $$dq=\rho\ dV$$
>   $$dq = \rho 4\pi r^2 \ dr$$
>   $$\rho = \frac{q_{in}}{V_{in}}=\frac{Q_{total}}{V_{total}}$$

Which leads me to say then that:

$$\frac{q_{in}}{\frac{4}{3}\pi a^3}\cdot\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3=Q$$
Then when I take the derivative of both sides I get:

$$\frac{3q_{in}r^2}{a^3}dr=dQ$$

$$k\int \frac{3q_{in}r^2}{r^2a^3}dr$$
$$E=3k\frac{q_{in}}{a^3}r$$

Comment: And explanation of the physics and symbols would greatly enable focused answers.

Comment: @avs Did you read the last question?

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to follow links or look into sources.  (Didn't even notice your link.)

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. It is alright to reference another question to give more background, but you should reproduce enough here to allow people to understand your question without having to follow the link. However, you've added several symbols to your calculation that are not defined here, nor are they defined in the other question. So we have to guess what it is you mean. Sorry, not interested in guessing.

Comment: Do the dimensions agree?

Comment: Charge per unit volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula next to last is not correct. Let's say that the original sphere has radius $a$, and we want to calculate the electric field at some distance $R$ from the center. A spherical shell that you use for integration has a radius $r$, with $0\le r\le R$. The electric field due to this shell is $\frac{dQ}{R^2}$, and not $\frac{dQ}{r^2}$ as you have used in your calculations. Then, you get $$E=k\int_0^R\frac{dQ(r)}{R^2}=k\frac 1{R^2}q_{in}=k\frac{Q}{R^2}\frac{R^3}{a^3}=\frac{kQR}{a^3}$$